# Wireless issues with Vaio Flip 14a

Tags: wireless, vaio

Edit: The output using lspci command

```
mobtaker@Ebtkar:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics            Controller (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 09) 00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

installed Ubuntu 14.04 to my new machine, but the wireless does not work. I tried few tricks like rfkill command but nothing worked :( The machine does not have a wireless button.
Thanks in advqce for your help

Comment: You'll need to provide us with some more information. Generally, on linux, the steps to get a new driver working are: 1) determine what the hardware is 2) Figure out what the proper driver for that software is 3) Install the driver. So, can you tell us the chipset? The lspci command might help with that, as well as searching in dmesg for any wireless error messages.

Comment: Hey Javanix 36. I edited my post which has the hardware (I think) thanka

Comment: @Ahmad, thanks for your question. It's much much easier to read if you format the output of commands into a block so the information doesn't flow together. You can do that by preceeding each line with four blanks, or put it between the html codes <pre> and </pre>. I hope someone can help you.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you have a Broadcom BCM43142 network adapter.

```
...
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
...
```

Some googling around [reveals](http://kb.openstudioproject.com/content/ubuntu/install-broadcom-bcm43142-driver-ubuntu) that this functionality may be provided by the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package.

Give this command a try:

`sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`

That should pull in the proper dependencies that are required to build and install on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Yep. It worked perfectly :) Thanks for the help!